# Jquerymobile buttons are shown only first apperance of the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jquery mobile code. I am using the code above to append a dynamic html code for my application.

```
$("#tab3").click(function() {
    $('#HaberIcerik').html(" <img src='img/izto_header.png' height=auto width=100% class='img2'  > ");
    $('#HaberIcerik').append("  <div class='zoomTab'><a href='#' data-role='button' class='plus'>+</a><a href='#' data-role='button' class='minus'>-</a></div>");
});
```

When the page loads first, everything works perfectly. However when I move to the main page and click my tab3 page again buttons are shown only as links,not with button styles.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're not refreshing your button's styles. So, you must add it after `append()`

```
  $(document).on("click", "#tab3", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#HaberIcerik').html("<img src='http://www.ndaccess.com/Sample/Images/Image1.jpg' height=auto width=100% class='img2' > ");
        $('#HaberIcerik').append("<div class='zoomTab'><a href='#' data-role='button' class='plus'>+</a><a href='#' data-role='button' class='minus'>-</a></div>").promise().done(function () {
            //wait till everything is appended
            $(this).find("a").buttonMarkup("refresh");
        });
    });
```

For more info see docs : http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh

And here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/cTdkN/